# PHP unpack zip and insert content into database

Tags: php, database, zip, unpack

I need to be able to extract a zip file, and insert the names of the files in the zip file into a database.

I've searched around, and found multiple scripts to unpack a zip file, but it seems that I'm not able to get the individual filenames of the files in the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably suggest to use two system calls:

1) unzip to tmp folder
2) read files from that folder

(updated full working script):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["fsubmit"])){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_FILES);
    $tmp_dir = "tmp/" . microtime(true);
    if (!file_exists($tmp_dir)){
        mkdir($tmp_dir);
    }
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $tmp_dir . "/a.zip");
        exec("unzip -z -j $tmp_dir $tmp_dir" . "/a.zip");
        exec("ls $tmp_dir", $out);
        echo "Files in the archive:\n";
        foreach ($out as $file){
            $file = trim($file);
            echo "File: $file,", filesize($tmp_dir . "/" . $file)."b\n";
        }
        exec("rm -rf $tmp_dir");
    }
} else {
?>
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="fsubmit" value="upload">
</form>
<?
}
```

Pre-requisites
0) will work if you are under unix/linux/mac (won't work under windows)
1) create test.php and paste in it the code above
2) make sure in the same folder where test.php, is folder tmp
3) make sure apache user can write that folder (e.g. chmod 777 tmp)
4) make sure your php allows file uploads
5) make sure your server has "unzip" command line tool

Regards.

Comment: Yeah okay, so I got that, but all that happens now, is the $tmp_dir being created.   

the file looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/19CGCaXg

Comment: where is zip file coming from? in my example it assumes it's uploaded through a form e.g. <input name="file" type="file" />

Comment: also, make sure "unzip" is present on your server.

Comment: Yeah, the zip is uploaded through af form.

Comment: is zip file being copied in the temporary folder?

Comment: No, the temp folder is created, but is left empty.

Comment: see updated code above, just follow instructions below the script.